# jQuery form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

My goal is:
When for is submitted:

- a validation on form is made : *OK*
- an ajax is called to see that username and password do match : *OK*
- if they don't match, display an error: *OK*
- if they match, then REALLY SUBMIT the form: *NOT OK*.

Infact the trouble is, I cannot submit the form since there is a jquery submit event on it!

```
function form1Submit() {
var username=$('#username').val();
var password=$('#password').val();
if (username.length<2) {
    return false;
}
if (password.length<2) {
    return false;
}
$.post("check.php", { username: username, password:password }, function(data) {
    if (data=="ko") {
        alert('bad password');
        return false;
    } else {
    //to be done here !
    }
});
    return false;
}
function init() {
   $('#form1').submit(function(){
        return form1Submit();
    })
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    init();
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call the native submit event, so do this:

```
$('#form1').submit(form1Submit);
```

Then in your post callback do this:

```
$.post("check.php", { username: username, password:password }, function(data) {
    if (data=="ko") {
        alert('bad password');
    } else {
        this.submit();
    }
});
```

The `this.submit()` isn't calling he jQuery [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) trigger function, but rather the native `<form>` [`.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit) function.

Answer (score 1):

The `return false` is blocking the default form submit action. You have *either* to `return true` from the `form1Submit()` function to let the default form submit action do its job, *or* to add another `$.post()` inside the `else` which submits the data to the form asynchronously, if your intent was to do it using ajaxical powers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that form1Submit always returns false.

Answer (score 1):

```
function form1Submit(ev, ok) {

  ev.stopPropagation();

  ok = (typeof ok != 'undefined') ? ok : false;

  if (ok)
    return true;

  var username=$('#username').val(),
      password=$('#password').val(),
      selfForm = this;

  if (username.length < 2)
    return false;

  if (password.length < 2)
    return false;

  $.post("check.php", { username: username, password:password }, function(data) {
    if (data=="ko") {
      alert('bad password');
    } else {
      $(selfForm).trigger('submit', [true]); // again submit but with ok parameter
    }
  });

  return false;
}

function init() {
   $('#form1').bind('submit', form1Submit);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    init();
})
```

Comment: `$(selfForm).trigger('submit', [true]);` seems to do the trick. Just replace selfform with the ID of the form and you will be all set. For example: `$('#frm_test').trigger('submit', [true]); `

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {

        $("#search_form").validate({
            rules: {
                class_id: {
                    required:true,
                },
                section_id: {
                    required:true,
                },
                period_id: {
                    required:true,
                },
            },
            messages:{
                class_id: {
                    required:'Class id is required',
                },
                section_id: {
                    required:'Section id is required',
                },
                period_id: {
                    required:'Month is required',
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {

               //Your ajax code
               return false;
           }
        });

    });
```