# How to call a javascript function on div load after server side call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and once it gets submitted successfully , then after the roundtrip from the server I get a success message displayed on the same page.

I am using the following code:

```
<s:if test="%{#session.str==1}" >
<div onload="showSuccessToast();">
  <button onclick="showSuccessToast();"></button>
</div>
</s:if>
```

Now when I return from the server (form submit successful) then the button is displayed and on its `onClick` event the `showSuccessToast()` is called but when I expect div to call this function on the `onload` event it has no effect.

Any idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify it as follows which is kind of simulating "on-load-div":

```
<s:if test="%{#session.str==1}" >
<div>
  <button onclick="showSuccessToast();"></button>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      showSuccessToast();
  </script>
</div>
</s:if>
```

Comment: I have got one more problem , when I reload the page the form gets automatically submitted as the form-action is called. Any fix for this.

Comment: Irrespective of the server-side technology (jsp/asp/php etc.,), the client side javascript code would be the same. These links are a good resource on ajax form submit: http://api.jquery.com/submit/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638750/jquery-form-submit